# Discord bot sends message with wrong value or no message at all

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

Depending on where I place the Discord message code determines whether I get a message with wrong info or no message at all.

Main function calls several smaller functions that get the data I need from an API and then format it.  Lastly, it then calls the discord.

I have tried placing [const Discord = require('discord.js'); and const client = new Discord.Client(); client.login(process.env.SECRET);] up in the (1) global area, (2) in the discord function, and (3)right before the call to Main.

I have tried placing the message sending code (1) in its own discord function, (2) right before the call to Main.

If I call the discord function inside of the main function, nothing happens.  If I call it after calling Main, then the message sends, but the Global variables are null instead of the data I assigned to them.

```
Global variables = null;


Main function{

call Secondary()

call Formatting()

call Discord()

}

Secondary function{

API stuff

assign part of API data to Global variables

}

Formatting function{

format Global variables

}

Discord function{

send Global variables

}


call Main function()
```

What should be happening:

-Make API request (OK)

-Receive API data (OK)

-Assign portion of the data to Global variable (OK)

-Format Global variable (OK)

-Send discord message with Global variable data (NOT OK)

Comment: Are any functions running async? There might be race conditions between the different functions.

Comment: Yes, they all are.  Though I tried no async for the discord one; didn't change any results.  What's the best solution to make the discord message wait until the globals have been updated?

Comment: Either chain them with Promise.then()... or use async/await in the main function

Comment: Inside main I tried 'await discordFunction(global variables)' and nothing happens.  No errors. No message sent.  Does discord.js not like being broken up into functions?

Comment: UPDATE: I couldn't get await to work; so I opted with setInterval.  Thank you for your help.